# how do I hide the dynamic loaded template on click of the same button angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Trying to show and hide the template on click of the same button, but unable to get the write thing..

Added plunker is the tried demo link:

[Demo Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/siPDCWOWOPNwsr9JSSw8?p=preview)

Tried `ng-click="cClick()=!cClick()"`, but it is not at all working...

Can't use two buttons, because what ever dynamic loaded template is shown as a pop-up in all the screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the template to null whenever it's set already:

```
 $scope.cClick = function() {
       if($scope.template)
         $scope.template = null;
       else
         $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
   }
```

new plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/HotKqNXqZIRYWhSxIuli?p=preview